# MongoDB highlights

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm just getting started with MongoDB and the whole principle of NoSQL and I'm really enjoying the experience.

Has anyone got any suggestions of features that I should look into?

Has anyone come across any in-depth tutorials?

One thing that in particular I'm interested in is how to deal with what is annalagous to a change in schema.  If a column is added to a table, all records would have this new column.  Seemingly in Mongo, if a document ends up with a new property only new documents would have this property with an update being required to add this onto all other docuemts.  Is there a better approach to this or am fixating on non-existent problems?

Comment: I'm at the beginning of my journey and have been looking through the documentation on http://www.mongodb.org/. It provides a whole lot of detail and a ends up with a rather steep learning curve.  I'm keen to find a tutorial that will help me digest the salient points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to realise that data-modeling is going to be *totally* different from a relational database. I would suggest that you follow a few schema design presentations that are available through http://www.10gen.com/presentations (unselect "featured" and select "view all" and search for "schema"). http://www.10gen.com/presentations/webinar/mongodb-schema-design-how-to-think-non-relational is a particularly good one.

There are lots of other "schema design" tutorials online as well, and I have to stress that simply converting your relational schema into MongoDB is not going to get the best out of MongoDB as it's a totally different approach.